# pointer to pointer to a Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

in following code `&pA` before and after `foo` function must be different, but it's the same, therefore `A` become `null`. It's worth mentioning `result_Mat` in `foo` have value and so `ppA` is not `null`. why `A` become null and how to fix?

```
void main()
{
  // some code
  Mat A;
  uchar* pA = A.data;
  cout << &pA << endl;
  foo(&pA);
  cout << &pA << endl;
  // some code
}
void foo(uchar** ppA)
{
  Mat result_Mat;
  // some code
  *ppA= result_Mat.data;
  // some code
}
```

Comment: "It's worth mentioning result_Mat in foo have value" -- but not in the code you show. Start by providing a [mcve] that actually corresponds to the problem in question.

Comment: what happen if you pass `*pA` to foo,

Comment: Are you expecting `pA` to *move*? A variable is always in the same place. You're assigning a new value to `pA`. Not to `&pA`, and not to `A.data`.

Comment: @molbdnilo please give me your description as a answer but with more details.

Comment: Also, given that `result_Mat` goes out of scope at the end of `foo`, and it owns the memory pointed to by its `data` member (unless you omitted another critical detail), that memory will be deallocated when the function ends. As such, anything it returns seems rather useless.

Comment: A.data is null all the time because you don't create any data memory for that matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main()
{
  Mat A;
  uchar* pA = A.data;  // pA points to A.data, let's say it's 0xAAAAAAAA
  cout << &pA << endl; // Let's say &pA is 0xBBBBBBBB
  foo(&pA); // Call to foo with pA's address, 0xBBBBBBBB

void foo(uchar** ppA) // ppA points to pA's address, 0xBBBBBBBB
                      // If you dereference ppA it will give you the value of
                      // the pointer at 0xBBBBBBBB, which is 0xAAAAAAAA
{
  Mat result_Mat;
  *ppA= result_Mat.data; // You're changing the original pA pointer value 
                         // from 0xAAAAAAAA to address of result_Mat.data, 
                         // let's say for example 0xCCCCCCCC.
}

// Back in the main function
cout << &pA; // &pA hasn't changed. Value of pA used to be 0xAAAAAAAA, you 
             // sent it to the foo function and changed its value to 0xCCCCCCCC.

}
```

The actual address where the pointer resides, in other words the 4 or 8 bytes it may take up to "store" the address of somewhere is &pA and it was never changed. It can't be changed because you declare it  as you would any other variable on the stack, and these local variables don't change their address.

Comment: yes, you're right: " the address of somewhere is &pA and it was never changed." but how can i fix this code? I wouldn't like to `A` become null.

Comment: @Saeid Pointers store a number/address. If you want read that address you get it with p, not &p. So if you do Mat A; uchar* pA = A.data; pA points to A.data, pA equals A.data. When you send it to foo() you create another pointer ppA that points to p. When you dereference ppA with asterisk *ppA you get the value of pA, which is pointing to A.data. When you do *ppA = result_Mat.data the original pA pointer points to this result_Mat.data. pA no longer points to original matrix A in main(). And when foo() exits pA is either null or pointing to invalid memory, because result_Mat is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

As you said

> in following code &pA before and after foo function must be different

but the why should the address of `pA` (i.e. `&pA`) change if you change if you try to change the contents of that same pointer `pA` inside the foo function.

I think you are looking for the `*` i.e. the `dereferenc`ing operator to check the value pointed to by a pointer